# Make Switch-Button (which is in an AlertDialog) do something when it's state changes

Tags: android, xamarin, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

So I want to create a little popup options menu within my Activity. I already have this code which shows the menu

```
public void ShowOptionsDialog()
    {
        Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder optionDialog = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        optionDialog.SetTitle("Optionen");            
        optionDialog.SetView(Resource.Layout.Options);
        optionDialog.Show();            
    }
```

**Resource.Layout.Options** contains the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">
    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/previewSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:checked="true"
        android:hint="Preview der Dokumente anzeigen"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How exactly do I tell the app to do something when the Switch is pressed (on/off)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an event handler on the `SwitchCompat` and act on any changes that the user makes:

Note: v7 switch does not contains `Android.Resource.Id.Custom` and thus will return null from `FindViewById`, so here we create our own `FrameLayout`:

```
protected void ShowOptionsDialog()
{
    Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder optionDialog = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    optionDialog.SetTitle("Optionen");
    // Android.Resource.Id.Custom does not exist within v7 alertdialog 
    var frameLayout = new FrameLayout (optionDialog.Context);
    optionDialog.SetView(frameLayout);
    Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog alert = optionDialog.Create();
    var myView = alert.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.Options, frameLayout);
    var mySwitch = myView.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.SwitchCompat> (Resource.Id.previewSwitch); 
    mySwitch.CheckedChange += (object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) => {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.IsChecked);
    };
    alert.Show ();
}
```

[image]

**Note:** The Android docs state to do the following for adding a custom view to your Switch, the issue is with `SwitchCompat`, that view does not exist.

```
 FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.custom);
 fl.addView(myView, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Comment: Already tried something similar to what you suggest and when I use your code I get the same error: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

But I don't understand why...

Comment: I get this error now:
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
:/

Comment: @fbueckle I updated the code again, the `custom` view does not exist in v7, so here is a workaround that does actually work.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for the in detail answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: @fbueckle no problem, so strange about the issues with the embedded "custom" view resource in this `Switch` compatibility version... but it works ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to get a reference to your switch. An easy way to get one would be to create the switch view in code. This would change your code to something like that:

```
public void ShowOptionsDialog()
{
    var switchView = new Android.Support.V7.Widget.SwitchCompat(this);
    switchView.CheckedChange += (object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) => { //Do stuff depending on state };

    Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder optionDialog = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    optionDialog.SetTitle("Optionen");            
    optionDialog.SetView(switchCompat);
    optionDialog.Show();            
}
```